# Existence of a linear map from a dense space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For any $x \in X$, define the set $\mathcal{F}(X) = \overline{\operatorname{span} \{ \delta_x : x \in X \}}$ where $\delta_x(f)=f(x)$ for all $f \in$ $\operatorname{Lip}_0(X)$.

The set $\operatorname{Lip}_0(X)$ is the set of all real-valued Lipschitz functions which vanish at $0$.

Note that $\delta_x$ is an evaluation functional on $\operatorname{Lip}_0(X)$.

Suppose that $X$ is a separable Banach space. Let $D$ to be a dense subspace of $X$ and spanned by $\{ x_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

In [Theorem $3.1$](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf)(page $128$), in the proof, the author mentions the following:

> We denote by $R_D$ the linear map from $D$ to $\mathcal{F}(X)$ which satisfies $R_D(x_n)=\phi_n$.

Question: Why such linear map exists and satisfies the equation?

Comment: You're just defining a linear map on a basis. You haven't defined $\phi_n$ but that doesn't seem important.

Comment: By basis, do you mean $\{x_n\}$?